# Simpy Container Questions

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

**Full disclosure**: I am a student who has likely messed up some conventions, notation and best practices. I warmly welcome feedback.

I am trying to implement a version of the gas station example found in the SimPy documentation, attached here:

```
Covers:

- Resources: Resource
- Resources: Container
- Waiting for other processes

Scenario:
  A gas station has a limited number of gas pumps that share a common
  fuel reservoir. Cars randomly arrive at the gas station, request one
  of the fuel pumps and start refueling from that reservoir.

  A gas station control process observes the gas station's fuel level
  and calls a tank truck for refueling if the station's level drops
  below a threshold.


import itertools
import random

import simpy


RANDOM_SEED = 42
GAS_STATION_SIZE = 200     # liters
THRESHOLD = 10             # Threshold for calling the tank truck (in %)
FUEL_TANK_SIZE = 50        # liters
FUEL_TANK_LEVEL = [5, 25]  # Min/max levels of fuel tanks (in liters)
REFUELING_SPEED = 2        # liters / second
TANK_TRUCK_TIME = 300      # Seconds it takes the tank truck to arrive
T_INTER = [30, 300]        # Create a car every [min, max] seconds
SIM_TIME = 1000            # Simulation time in seconds


def car(name, env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """A car arrives at the gas station for refueling.

    It requests one of the gas station's fuel pumps and tries to get the
    desired amount of gas from it. If the stations reservoir is
    depleted, the car has to wait for the tank truck to arrive.

    """
    fuel_tank_level = random.randint(*FUEL_TANK_LEVEL)
    print('%s arriving at gas station at %.1f' % (name, env.now))
    with gas_station.request() as req:
        start = env.now
        # Request one of the gas pumps
        yield req

        # Get the required amount of fuel
        liters_required = FUEL_TANK_SIZE - fuel_tank_level
        yield fuel_pump.get(liters_required)

        # The "actual" refueling process takes some time
        yield env.timeout(liters_required / REFUELING_SPEED)

        print('%s finished refueling in %.1f seconds.' % (name,
                                                          env.now - start))


def gas_station_control(env, fuel_pump):
    """Periodically check the level of the *fuel_pump* and call the tank
    truck if the level falls below a threshold."""
    while True:
        if fuel_pump.level / fuel_pump.capacity * 100 < THRESHOLD:
            # We need to call the tank truck now!
            print('Calling tank truck at %d' % env.now)
            # Wait for the tank truck to arrive and refuel the station
            yield env.process(tank_truck(env, fuel_pump))

        yield env.timeout(10)  # Check every 10 seconds


def tank_truck(env, fuel_pump):
    """Arrives at the gas station after a certain delay and refuels it."""
    yield env.timeout(TANK_TRUCK_TIME)
    print('Tank truck arriving at time %d' % env.now)
    amount = fuel_pump.capacity - fuel_pump.level
    print('Tank truck refuelling %.1f liters.' % amount)
    yield fuel_pump.put(amount)


def car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """Generate new cars that arrive at the gas station."""
    for i in itertools.count():
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(*T_INTER))
        env.process(car('Car %d' % i, env, gas_station, fuel_pump))


# Setup and start the simulation
print('Gas Station refuelling')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Create environment and start processes
env = simpy.Environment()
gas_station = simpy.Resource(env, 2)
fuel_pump = simpy.Container(env, GAS_STATION_SIZE, init=GAS_STATION_SIZE)
env.process(gas_station_control(env, fuel_pump))
env.process(car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump))

# Execute!
env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

My biggest source of frustration has been to try to implement some sort of way to yield the container to the tank truck such that no cars may get gas while the gas station is replenishing its stock of gas (via the tank truck). I have tried to put if statements in the car definition to check the status of the gas stations fuel stock or yield the resource when the loop in the gas_station_control condition is triggered but have been unsuccessful.

My scenario is:
3 random cars in a set time-frame. The capacity of the gas station is 1.5 tanks of gas, and it takes 3 hours for a car to pump one load. Once that car leaves I need to refill my gas stations reservoir which takes 4 hours(if the level=.5 @ a rate of .25 loads/hour, 6 hours to fill all 1.5 tanks). I also need to make sure that if no car is currently waiting in the queue I should be refilling the reservoir, irregardless if I am out of the current time frame where cars may pull up. I need to make sure that I am logging the time that each car waits in the queue.

Comment: in def tank_truck(env, fuel_pump):  will adding a yield env.timeout({some taker fill time}) just before the yield fuel_pump.put(ammount) fix the first sim?

Comment: That just delays when the fuel level is replenished but still allows the cars to pull from the reservoir in the mean time. They are sharing the container so I am inclined to believe it has something to do with the definition of car.

Comment: does not the gas station control access to the containers?  so if you want the gas truck to have total control of the containers it will have to seize both gas station resources first.  I would start with this, but if you do not want the truck to wait for total access you can use interrupts or priority resource queues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure what you trying to do.  Why cannot the cars have a pending request while the truck is replenishing the container?  Those requests do not block the truck from adding to the container.

Any way, I took a stab at it and here is what I cam up with

In this version, when the car gets to the pump it checks if the container has enough gas to refuel the car.  If it does it will make the container request.  If it does not, it will wait for the truck to arrive and replenish the gas station and then make the container request.  The car knows when replenishment is done because I added a replenish_event to the gas_station which gets triggered by the truck when the truck finishes replenishment.  If the car needs to wait, it can yield to this event. Note that more then one car can yield to this event.

```
"""
Covers:

- Resources: Resource
- Resources: Container
- Waiting for other processes

Scenario:
  A gas station has a limited number of gas pumps that share a common
  fuel reservoir. Cars randomly arrive at the gas station, request one
  of the fuel pumps and start refueling from that reservoir.

  A gas station control process observes the gas station's fuel level
  and calls a tank truck for refueling if the station's level drops
  below a threshold.

Updated my Michel R. Gibbs
Car does not make a request for gas amount unless it can get full amount.
If cannot get full amount, will wait for truck to replenish before making request
"""

import itertools
import random

import simpy


RANDOM_SEED = 42
GAS_STATION_SIZE = 200     # liters
THRESHOLD = 10             # Threshold for calling the tank truck (in %)
FUEL_TANK_SIZE = 50        # liters
FUEL_TANK_LEVEL = [5, 25]  # Min/max levels of fuel tanks (in liters)
REFUELING_SPEED = 2        # liters / second
TANK_TRUCK_TIME = 300      # Seconds it takes the tank truck to arrive
T_INTER = [30, 300]        # Create a car every [min, max] seconds
SIM_TIME = 2000            # Simulation time in seconds
REPLENISHMENT_SPEED = 20   # linters / second for tanker truck to refill gas staiion


def car(name, env, gas_station, fuel_pump, replenish_event):
    """A car arrives at the gas station for refueling.

    It requests one of the gas station's fuel pumps and tries to get the
    desired amount of gas from it. If the stations reservoir is
    depleted, the car has to wait for the tank truck to arrive.

    """
    fuel_tank_level = random.randint(*FUEL_TANK_LEVEL)
    print('%s arriving at gas station at %.1f' % (name, env.now))
    with gas_station.request() as req:
        start = env.now
        # Request one of the gas pumps
        yield req
        print('%s exit queue and started pumping gas at %.1f' % (name, env.now))
        # Get the required amount of fuel
        liters_required = FUEL_TANK_SIZE - fuel_tank_level
        
        # check if amount is available
        while liters_required > fuel_pump.level:
            # use a while in case another car uses up the replenishment

            # wait for truck
            print('%s waiting for fuel truck before starting to pump %.1f' % (name, env.now))
            yield replenish_event

        yield fuel_pump.get(liters_required)

        # The "actual" refueling process takes some time
        yield env.timeout(liters_required / REFUELING_SPEED)

        print('%s finished refueling in %.1f seconds.' % (name,
                                                          env.now - start))


def gas_station_control(env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """
    Periodically check the level of the *fuel_pump* and call the tank
    truck if the level falls below a threshold.
    """
    
    gas_station.replenish_event = env.event()
    while True:
        if fuel_pump.level / fuel_pump.capacity * 100 < THRESHOLD:
            # We need to call the tank truck now!
            print('Calling tank truck at %d' % env.now)
            env.process(tank_truck(env, fuel_pump, gas_station.replenish_event))

            # yield until replenishment is finished
            yield gas_station.replenish_event

            # reset event for next replenishment
            gas_station.replenish_event = env.event()

        yield env.timeout(10)  # Check every 10 seconds


def tank_truck(env, fuel_pump, replenish_event):
    """
    Arrives at the gas station after a certain delay and refuels it.
    """
    yield env.timeout(TANK_TRUCK_TIME)
    print('Tank truck arriving at time %d' % env.now)
    
    amount = fuel_pump.capacity - fuel_pump.level
    replem_time = amount / REPLENISHMENT_SPEED
    yield env.timeout(replem_time)

    print('Tank truck replenshied %.1f liters at time %.1f.' % (amount, env.now))
    yield fuel_pump.put(amount)

    # let any listeners know replenishment is done
    replenish_event.succeed()


def car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump):
    """
    Generate new cars that arrive at the gas station.
    """
    for i in itertools.count():
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(*T_INTER))
        env.process(car('Car %d' % i, env, gas_station, fuel_pump, gas_station.replenish_event))


# Setup and start the simulation
print('Gas Station refuelling')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Create environment and start processes
env = simpy.Environment()
gas_station = simpy.Resource(env, 2)
fuel_pump = simpy.Container(env, GAS_STATION_SIZE, init=GAS_STATION_SIZE)
env.process(gas_station_control(env, gas_station, fuel_pump))
env.process(car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump))

# Execute!
env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! This is great and very close to what I needed for an end goal. I actually ended up programming it in straight python with no SimPy library. For my purposes there was a definite trade off between using SimPy or not; scheduling 'random' arrivals in a specified time window was easy in Python whereas in SimPy it was more involved. It was a great introduction to the library and discrete time simulation in general, you can find my actual problem prompt here: https://www.mathmodels.org/Problems/1993/MCM-A/1993A.pdf

Comment: sounds more like a optimization problem.  Python has a optimization pack called Pulp, but this would not be a simple problem

Comment: My solution can be found at https://github.com/jdellag/coaltipple if you care to take a look